# Recalculating Neo4J relationships based on chain of relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a long chain of relations:

```
:User can have multiple :Territory(ies)
:Account can belong in multiple :Territory(ies)
:Account can be assigned to a multiple :User(s)
:Account can have an :Invoice(s)
:Invoice can have an :InvoiceEntry(ies)
```

To sum up:

```
:User-[:BELONGS_TO]->:Territory<-[:EXISTS_IN]-:Account-[:ISSUED]->:Invoice-[:HAS]->:InvoiceEntry
```

I can simplify the relation to

```
:User-[:CAN_SEE]->:Invoice
```

Since I'm not proficient with Cypher, my questions are:

#### Question #1.

What would be the query to refresh the relationships between :User and :Invoice once the :Account is being removed from :Territory and leave valid relationships :CAN_SEE untouched.

#### Question #2.

Same as above but :User is removed from :Territory and can no longer see :Invoice.

### UPDATE 16.06.23

My primary relation chain is `:User -> :Territory <- :Account -> :Invoice`.
`:User -> :Territory` relation is provided by the Active Directory.
`:Account -> :Territory` and `:Account -> Invoice` relations are fetched from ERP system.

In order to avoid costly calculation, because single `:User` can have hundreds of `:Territory` and one `:Account` can be in a hundreds of `:Territory`, I want to introduce a "shortcut" relationship `:User-[:CAN_SEE]->:Invoice`.

Example case:

`U1` belongs to `T1`, `T2`, `T3`.
`A1` exists in `T1`, `T4`.
`A2` exists in `T3`, `T4`.
`A3` exists in `T1`, `T2`, `T4`.
`A1` issued `I1`.
`A2` issued `I2`.
`A3` issued `I3`.

Here, I would end up having it simplified to:
`U1` can see `I1`, `I2`, `I3`.

#### Follow-up to Question #1:

I receive a payload that the ERP detached `A1` and `A3` from `T1`.
I remove `A1->T1`, `A3->T1` relationships.
I need to recalculate `[:CAN_SEE]` since U1 loses `[:CAN_SEE]` to `I1` because `U1` to `A1` has no longer valid territory relations. `U1` still can see `I3` because `A3` loses `T1` but `T2` ensures the chain to `I3`.

How would the query look like?

#### Follow-up to Question #2:

Active Directory got updated:
`U1` is detached from `T1`.
`U1` is no longer able to see `I1`.

How would the query look like in this situation.

Putting my questions in another words:

I know how to create new relationships based on existing ones. I have trouble understanding how to re-invalidate old ones and remove those if no longer valid.

Comment: For #1: Is it the case that the `CAN_SEE` relationships already exist and you just want to remove the `Account` nodes, or are you asking how to create the `CAN_SEE` relationships and remove the `Account` nodes at the same time? For #2: It sounds like you want to remove almost everything. Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: @cybersam I hope that I was able to introduce some clarification with my update.

Comment: Remember to evaluate the answers and possibly Accept or award an answer that works for you, _before_ your bounty expires.

Answer (score 1):

if I get the questions right,

1. you create :CAN_SEE relations with this query

   match (u:User)-->(:Territory)<--(:Account)-->(i:Invoice)
   merge (u)-[:CAN_SEE]->(i)

MERGE should prevent creation of multiple relations

2. & 3. if I get you right, in both case, you want to check that the path from user to invoice still exists and delete the CAN_SEE relation if the path is broken. the following query should do that

   match (u:User)-[r:CAN_SEE]-(i:Invoice) where not exists((u)-->(:Territory)<--(:Account)-->(i))
   delete r

do test before applying in production though, I did not test

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your questions are for updating a graph that already contains the appropriate `CAN_SEE` relationships.

1. Use the following query to update the graph when a specific account (say, `A1`) is deleted. The query uses [DETACH DELETE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/delete/#delete-a-node-with-all-its-relationships) to delete matching paths and all relationships (including `BELONGS_TO` and `CAN_SEE`) for all deleted nodes.

   ```
   MATCH p=(a:Account)-[:ISSUED]->(:Invoice)-[:HAS]->(:InvoiceEntry)
   WHERE a.id = 'A2'
   DETACH DELETE p
   ```
2. Use this query to disconnect a user (`U1`) from a territory (`T3`), and to delete all the `CAN_SEE` relationships from that user to all invoices issued by all accounts in the territory:

   ```
   MATCH  (u:User)-[bt:BELONGS_TO]->(t:Territory)<-[:EXISTS_IN]-(:Account)-[:ISSUED]->(:Invoice)<-[cs:CAN_SEE]-(u)
   WHERE u.id = 'U1' AND t.id = 'T3'
   DELETE bt, cs
   ```